$$ is finite-dimensional. $, $ are subspaces of $$. $ =  + $. Prove that there exists basis of $$ consisting of vectors in $\cup$
I'm self-studying linear algebra and can't find solution to the problem to verify my answer.
Suppose $$ is finite-dimensional and $, $ are subspaces of $$ such that $ =  + $. Prove that there exists a basis of $$ consisting of vectors in $\cup $.
My solution:
$v \in V$ can be written as $u + w$ where $u \in U$ and $w \in W$ because $V = U + W$. Let $u_1, u_2, \ldots u_n$ be basis of $U$ and $w_0, w_1, \ldots w_m$ be basis of $W$. So any $v$ can be written as $a_1u_1 + a_2u_2 + \ldots a_nu_n + b_1w_1 + b_2w_2 + \ldots b_mw_m$. That proves that $B = u_1, u_2, \ldots, u_n, w_1, w_2, \ldots, w_m$ spans $V$. If it's linear independent, then it's basis of $V$. Otherwise every spanning list can be reduced to basis: by linear dependence lemma there exists $b_k \in B$ and $b_k \in span\left(b_0, \ldots,b_{k-1}\right)$. If $b_k$ is removed then the span of the remaining list equals to the span $B$. After some number of steps algorithm terminates and resulting list contains some vectors from $U$ (possibly $0$) and some vectors from $W$ (possibly $0$). Resulting list is linear independent and spans $V$ thus is basis.
Is it correct?

Looks right to me.

This looks correct to me!  By the way, you can add the tag proof-verification when you're looking for confirmation like this.  (Although you're also supposed to point out where you think that you might have made a mistake.)

Seems like my solution is correct.

Your proof is correct but you can prove more generally that any subset $E$ which spans $V$ contains some basis $B$ of $V$ (and then consider the special case $E=U\cup W$, which spans $U+W$).
Simply take for $B$ some maximal linearly independent subset of $E$. You can even do this when $V$ is infinite dimensional, if you allow the use of Zorn's lemma.
